# Phonegap Android Facebook Connect Error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I'm trying to install the facebook-connect plugin for android using phonegap 3.0.0 (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). I keep getting the error cordova cannot be resolved in my ConnectPlugin.java file. This is what I read would fix it, but it has not.

Download the source ZIP for Cordova: http://cordova.apache.org/#download
Extract the 'cordova-android' ZIP anywhere. Inside will be a 'framework' folder.
In eclipse open the newly unzipped 'cordova-android/framework' folder as an existing project.
In eclipse right click on this new 'Cordova' project -> Properties -> Android . Make sure 'Is Library' is checked.
Right click on your app's project -> Properties -> Android. In the Library section choose 'Add'. Select your Cordova project.

I've also read many other answers in which they say the ConnectPlugin.java file needs to be changed (for other errors), but that does not solve my main issue which is the cordova cannot be resolved issue.

Also, I have an import tag `import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;` which also cannot be resolved, but I feel as if this is just because of the first problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

That version is outdated and does not support phonegap 3 +, try using it with phonegap 2 it will work